# uVa100- '3n+1' ~ time limit exceeded

Tags: c

I have finished learning the basic C language recently. I started solving uVa online judge problems. I solved the 3n+1 problem, ran it in my compiler. It was doing perfectly fine. But when I submitted online it said "Time Limit Exceeded." I can't seem to place the solution.

Here's the code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int execute(int x, int y)
{
    int i, n, k, maxCycle=0;

    for(i=x; i<=y; ++i)
    {
        n=1;
        k=i;
        while(k!=1)
        {
            if(k%2==1)
                k=3*k+1;
            else
                k=k/2;
            n++;
        }
        if(n>=maxCycle)
            maxCycle=n;
    }
    return maxCycle;
}

int main()
{
    while(1)
    {
        int a, b, max;
        scanf("%d %d", &a, &b);
        max=execute(a, b);
        printf("%d %d %d\n", a, b, max);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You should include a brief description of the problem.

Comment: While you were "learning the basic C language recently", which book taught you to indent your code like this?!

Comment: That would be SO's editor.

Answer (score 3):

You are not breaking the input taking loop. 
Use `while ( scanf ("%d %d", &a, &b) != EOF )` when taking `a,b`in `main()`.
You should break the input taking loop otherwise it waits for more input.

```
int main()
{
    int a,b;
    while(scanf ("%d %d", &a, &b) != EOF )
    {
       int max;
       max=execute(a, b);
       printf("%d %d %d\n", a, b, max);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @Michael Sthuvo Stinson.: If this answer helped accept it.